# can't sort in mongo/mongoose with populate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I can't seem to sort this mongo/mongoose query. The first one returns the exact results, just not sorted in the opposite direction.

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({  
    username         : String,
    current          : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'News' },
    friends          : [{ user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}, status: String }],
    profile          : {...}
```

})

```
const NewsSchema  = new Schema({
    user       : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    owner      : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    date       : Date,
    desc       : String
});

const News = mongoose.model('News', NewsSchema);
const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

I've tried

```
.populate({
    path: 'friends.user',
    model: 'User',
    select: 'profile.firstname profile.lastname profile.avatar username current -_id',
    populate: {
        path: 'current',
        model: 'News',
        select: 'date owner desc',
        populate: {
            path: 'owner',
            model: 'User',
            select: 'profile.firstname profile.lastname profile.avatar username'
        },
    },
})
.sort({'current.date': -1})
```

as well as

```
.populate({
    path: 'friends.user',
    model: 'User',
    select: 'profile.firstname profile.lastname profile.avatar username current -_id',
    populate: {
        path: 'current',
            model: 'News',
            select: 'date owner desc',
            options: { sort: { date: -1 } }
        },
    })
```

and this one which gives an error

```
User.findOne({ _id: req.userId }, 'friends -_id')
.populate({
    path: 'friends.user',
    model: 'User',
    select: 'profile.firstname profile.lastname profile.avatar username current -_id',
    populate: {
        path: 'current',
        model: 'News',
        select: 'date owner desc',
    },
        options: { 
            sort: { date: -1 }
        }
    })

{
    "message": "MongooseError: Cannot populate with `sort` on path friends.user because it is a subproperty of a document array"
}
```

with the first and second one, it comes back as

```
{
    "friends": [
        {
            "_id": "5b51fd7c3f4ec33546a0664f",
            "user": {
                "profile": {
                    ...
                },
                "current": {
                    "date": "2018-07-20T15:19:00.968Z"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": "5b51fdb53f4ec33546a06655",
                "user": {
                    "profile": {
                        ...
                    },
                    "current": {
                       "date": "2018-07-20T15:19:45.102Z"
                    }
                }
            }
       ]
}
```

It should be reversed as "date": "2018-07-20T15:19:45.102Z" is more recent.

Is there a better more efficient way of doing the same thing with aggregate and lookup?

**Users collection**

```
 {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b51fd2a3f4ec33546a06648"),
        "profile" : {
            "firstname" : "user1",
            "lastname" : "user1"
            "avatar" : "user1.png"
        }
        "username" : "user1",
        "friends" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5b51fd7c3f4ec33546a0664f"),
                "user" : ObjectId("5b51fd643f4ec33546a0664c")
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5b51fdb53f4ec33546a06655"),
                "user" : ObjectId("5b51fd903f4ec33546a06652")
            }
        ],
        "__v" : 5,
        "current" : ObjectId("5b51fd2a3f4ec33546a06649")
},
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b51fd643f4ec33546a0664c"),
        "profile" : {
            "firstname" : "user2",
            "lastname" : "user2"
            "avatar" : "user2.png"
        }
        "friends" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5b51fdcd3f4ec33546a06658"),
                "user" : ObjectId("5b51fd2a3f4ec33546a06648")
            }
        ],
        "__v" : 5,
        "current" : ObjectId("5b51fd643f4ec33546a0664d"),
        "username" : "user2"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b51fd903f4ec33546a06652"),
        "profile" : {
            "firstname" : "user3",
            "lastname" : "user3"
            "avatar" : "user3.png"
        },
        "friends" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5b51fdce3f4ec33546a0665a"),
                "user" : ObjectId("5b51fd2a3f4ec33546a06648")
            }
        ],
        "__v" : 5,
        "current" : ObjectId("5b51fd903f4ec33546a06653"),
        "username" : "user3"
    }
```

**New collection**

```
 {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b51fd2a3f4ec33546a06649"),
        "user" : ObjectId("5b51fd2a3f4ec33546a06648"),
        "owner" : ObjectId("5b51fd2a3f4ec33546a06648"),
        "date" : ISODate("2018-07-20T15:18:02.962Z"),
        "desc" : "user1 gibberish",

        "__v" : 0
    }



    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b51fd643f4ec33546a0664d"),
        "user" : ObjectId("5b51fd643f4ec33546a0664c"),
        "owner" : ObjectId("5b51fd643f4ec33546a0664c"),
        "date" : ISODate("2018-07-20T15:19:00.968Z"),
        "desc" : "user2 gibberish",
        "__v" : 0
    }


    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b51fd903f4ec33546a06653"),
        "user" : ObjectId("5b51fd903f4ec33546a06652"),
        "owner" : ObjectId("5b51fd903f4ec33546a06652"),
        "date" : ISODate("2018-07-20T15:19:44.102Z"),
        "desc" : "user3 gibberish",
        "__v" : 0
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below aggregation

```
User.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.userId) } },
  { "$unwind": "$friends" },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": User.collection.name,
    "let": { "friendId": "$friends.user" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$_id", "$$friendId" ] } } },
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": News.collection.name,
        "let": { "current": "$current" },
        "pipeline": [
           { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$_id", "$$current" ] } } },
         ],
         "as": "current"
      }},
      { "$unwind": "$current" }
    ],
    "as": "friends.user"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$friends.user" },
  { "$sort": { "friends.user.current.date": 1 }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "username": { "$first": "$username" },
    "profile": { "$first": "$profile" },
    "friends": { "$push": "$friends" }
  }}
])
```

Comment: it does the same thing.

Comment: It does sorting with date... Isn't it?

Comment: I don't think it's sorting at all. I've updated the code and results in the post

Comment: Ok please post your all the three collections sample in the question I will explain you the `$lookup` query to do this

Comment: what's User.collection.name in this context? I'm getting "MongoError: exception: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$lookup'"

Comment: MongoDB shell version: 2.6.10
connecting to: test
> db.version()
2.6.10

Comment: That's too low version... You have to upgrade to 3.6 or above to use `$lookup`

Comment: very nice! it works for the most part. can you just explain a little bit about how it all works? also, I need owner populated through the User db like in the first example         select: 'date owner desc',
        populate: {
            path: 'owner',
            model: 'User',
            select: 'profile.firstname profile.lastname profile.avatar username'
        }, how do I do that with your code?

Comment: You can check for the explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49953780/lookup-multiple-levels-without-unwind... You can use `$project` to limit your fields just like select of populate