# How to populate an array of model instances inside a subdocument? MongoDB Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, database-design, schema

I have a subdocument that is nested as an array. Inside that subdocument I have references to other models. Using the `.Find` and `.Populate` methods I can receive the entire objects for single models referenced in the subdocument (check out Stop below) but not an array of model instances, Facts/Recommendations. For Facts/Recommendations I receive an array of object `_ids`. I can probably just take those `_ids` and make another query but this seems messy.

Is there a way to populate the array? Do I need to use Aggregate + $lookup? Is there a more Mongo way to restructure the Schema to simplify this?

Thank you for all and any help!

My subdocument called TourStop:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const TourStopSchema = new Schema({
    stop: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Stop',
        required:[true, 'must have a Stop'],
    },
    mandatory: {
        type:Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    check_in_time: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    order: {
        type:Number,
        required: [true, 'Must have an order']
    },
    facts: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Fact'
    }],
    recommendations: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Recommendation'
    }]
});


module.exports = TourStopSchema;
```

TourStops lives inside of Tour:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const TourStopSchema = require('../subdocs/tour_stop');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const tourSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type:String,
        required:[true,'Name is required!'],
        unique: true
    },
    city: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'City is required!']
    },
    tourStops:[TourStopSchema]
});

const Tour = mongoose.model('Tour', tourSchema);
module.exports = Tour;
```

`Stop` Schema which is populated just fine.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const LocationSchema = require('../subdocs/location');
const ImageSchema = require('../subdocs/image');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const stopSchema = new Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required:[true,'Must have a name!']
    },
    location:LocationSchema,
    categories: {
        type: [String],
        default:[]
    },
    images:{
        type:[ImageSchema],
        default:[]
    }
});

const Stop = mongoose.model('Stop', stopSchema);
module.exports = Stop;
```

And Fact Schema which is not populated correctly, instead returns an array of strings with the _ids

Fact:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const ImageSchema = require('../subdocs/image');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const factSchema = new Schema({
    stop: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'Stop',
        required:[true, 'A Fact must have a Stop!'],
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: [true,'A Fact must have a description!']
    },
    images: {
        type:[ImageSchema],
        default:[]
    }
});

const Fact = mongoose.model('Fact', factSchema);
module.exports = Fact;
```

And I'm running a test to check that the schema is properly hooked up to retrieve all the attributes of a TourStop:

```
it('saves a full relation graph', (done) => {
    User.findOne({ first_name: 'Dean' })
        .populate({
            // in that user find the tours property and load up all tours
            path: 'tours',
            // inside of all those tours, find the tourstops property and load all associated stops
            populate: {
                path: 'tour_stops.facts',
                model: 'Fact'
            },
            populate: {
                path: 'tour_stops.stop',
                model: 'Stop'
            }
        })
        // .populate('tours.tour_stops[0].facts')
        .then((user) => {
            // console.log(user.tours[0].tour_stops[0].stop);
            console.log(user.tours[0].tour_stops[0]);
            // console.log(Array.isArray(user.tours[0].tour_stops[0].facts))
            assert(user.first_name === 'Dean' );
            assert(user.tours.length === 1);
            assert(user.tours[0].name === "Awesome New Tour");
            assert(user.tours[0].tour_stops[0].stop.name === 'Jaffa Clock Tower');
            // assert(user.tours[0])
            // assert(user.blogPosts[0].title === 'JS is Great');
            // assert(user.blogPosts[0].comments[0].content === 'Congrats on great post!' );
            // assert(user.blogPosts[0].comments[0].user.name === 'Joe' )
            done();
        })
    })
```

Comment: You have 5-6 schemas, but you only show only one schema code. How can we understand the relations between schemas this way?

Comment: I will update to include the other relevant schemas! Thanks for any help.

Comment: What about tour schema?

Comment: TourStop is nested inside of Tour as a subdocument, I've added the Tour schema to reflect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to populate tours, stop, facts and recommendations.
Note in `model` property, we should not give string value, but the model itself. So you need to import them to your code.

```js
  User.findOne({ first_name: "Dean" })
    .populate({
      path: "tours",
      populate: {
        path: "tourStops.stop",
        model: Stop
      }
    })
    .populate({
      path: "tours",
      populate: {
        path: "tourStops.facts",
        model: Fact
      }
    })
    .populate({
      path: "tours",
      populate: {
        path: "tourStops.recommendations",
        model: Recommendation
      }
    })
    .then(user => {
       console.log(user);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks @SuleymanSah ! This is working! 

In this specific case it seems to do the job, I'm just running a test of the associations. However do you think it would be better to try to do this through .Aggregate & $lookup? 

Doing 3 separate .Populate calls to the DB seems heavy. Any opinion on this??

Comment: @ruskibenya another option is to use nested lookup as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49953780/lookup-multiple-levels-without-unwind). Since you used populate, I answered with populate, can you please consider accepting this as answer?